# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a otra pagina con fecth?

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch

Tengo un formulario que envío por fetch API a mi archivo PHP y lo que quiero es que una vez que se mandan los datos me redireccione a otra pagina

```
 //HAGO MIS VALIDACIONES
 // y una vez que todo sea correcto los mando este es un ejemplo de como mando los datos 

    fetch('../../models/InsertarRegistros.php', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            Accept: " application/json ",
            "Content-Type": " application/json "
        },
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log("Success form", data);
        
    });
```

Comment: que envie el formulario y despues redirreccione a otro lado? en el then

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido hacer una petición AJAX y después cargar otra página, en general, se usa AJAX para evitar recargar o enviar a otra página, mejorando la experiencia del usuario. El único uso que le veo es para inicio y fin de sesión, donde tal vez se tengan que cambiar menús, opciones y más contenido de la página, resultando más fácil una redirección.

Comment: Lo que quiero es hacer que me mande ala otra pagina junto datos y mostrar estos mismos datos junto con otros

Answer (score 0):

NO hay ningun problema si envias los datos y en la respuesta redireccionas

```
fetch('../../models/InsertarRegistros.php', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        Accept: " application/json ",
        "Content-Type": " application/json "
    },
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
 window.location.replace("http://miotrapgina.com");
    
});
```

Comment: si lo intente algo parecido pero no me funciono.
Probare así.

Comment: recuerrda que  InsertarRegistros.php debe retornar algo para poder que entre al then el fetch